# on click of a delete button i want to delete that specific row

Tags: android, listview

## on click of a delete button i want to delete that specific row

three files i am submitting here of my project,on click of a delete button i want to delete that specific row.

list_mobile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="50px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:src="@drawable/windowsmobile_logo" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px" >
</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="delete" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

listmobileactivity.java

```
package com.mkyong.android;
import com.mkyong.android.adaptor.MobileArrayAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
public class ListMobileActivity extends ListActivity {

static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Android", "iOS",
        "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_mobile,
    //      R.id.label, MOBILE_OS));

    setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));


}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    //get selected items
    String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}

}
```

mobilearrayadapter.java

```
package com.mkyong.android.adaptor;
import com.mkyong.android.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_mobile, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.equals("WindowsMobile")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windowsmobile_logo);
    } else if (s.equals("iOS")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
    } else if (s.equals("Blackberry")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
    }

    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you really need is, As I guess what you can do is first you need to remove particular value from values array (Ideally this should be an ArrayList), then call notifyDataSetChanged() method on adaptor instance.

Comment: on click of a delete button i want to delete that specific row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Rewrite your `mobilearrayadapter.java` to include click listener to button. And I recommended use `ArrayList<String>` instead `String[]` to easy add and remove rows

```
   import ...
.
.
.
public class MobileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public MobileArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_mobile, values);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    if(convertView == null)
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mobile, parent, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    Button delBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    delBtn..setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    delBtn.setTag(position);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    // Change icon based on name
    String s = values[position];

    System.out.println(s);

    if (s.equals("WindowsMobile")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.windowsmobile_logo);
    } else if (s.equals("iOS")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ios_logo);
    } else if (s.equals("Blackberry")) {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackberry_logo);
    } else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_logo);
    }

    return rowView;
}


private OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
            Toast.makeText(MainLocalListAdapter.this.context, ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// After remove row from list call this

notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to remove the item from the adapter and refresh the list.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    MobileArrayAdapter la = (MobileArrayAdapter) getListAdapter();
    la.remove(la.getItem(position));
    la.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: on button click i want..

Comment: Then use an `onClick` event on your button, instead of the `ListView`'s `onClick`

Comment: but error is coming at la.remove.it says method is undefined

Comment: Please post your `Button`'s `onClick` code

Comment: i am posting code of listview's onclick.

Comment: @Override
 
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     ListAdapter la = getListAdapter();
     la.remove(la.getItem(position));
     la.notifyDatasetChanged();
 }

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to cast the `ListAdapter` to `MobileArrayAdapter`. I've updated answer

Comment: now same error coming at  la.notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: `notifyDataSetChanged` has a capital S. Modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
public class ListMobileActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Android", "iOS",
"WindowsMobile", "Blackberry"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

```
//setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter&lt;String&gt;(this, R.layout.list_mobile,
    //      R.id.label, MOBILE_OS));
```

```
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
setListAdapter(new MobileArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

//get selected items
String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Android", "iOS",
"WindowsMobile", "Blackberry"};
String[] newArray = new String[MOBILE_OS.length()-1];
[tmp] =0;
for(int i=0;i<MOBILE_OS.length();i++){
if(i!=position){
newArray[tmp] = MOBILE_OS[i];
tmp++;
}
} 
MOBILE_OS = newArray;
onResume();

}
```